# Yii logs showing exception for wp-login.php, however, I don't have WordPress

Tags: yii

I am using Yii 1.x, Yii internal log file is showing an exception for `wp-login.php`, however, I don't have WordPress installed on my server. (I get this message on my local as well)

```
XXXX/XX/XX XX:XX:XX [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "wp-login.php".' in /var/www/html/framework/web/CWebApplication.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('wp-login.php')
#1 /var/www/html/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /var/www/html/index.php(18): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/wp-login.php
```

Can anyone tell me why I am receiving such error?

Answer (score 0):

This is log for `404 Not Found` error. So this only means that someone is trying to access `/wp-login.php` URL in your domain. WordPress is the most popular CMS and internet is full of bots which searches WordPress installation on every server/domain and tries to brute-force login form. So you should not worry about it - if you don't have a WordPress installation, then bot definitely will not be able to login into it. :)

But it may be good idea to exclude 404 HTTP errors from regular application logs - bots will generate hundreds of such logs in your app, and usually you want to ignore it (as opposed to regular logs).

```
[
    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
    'levels' => 'error, warning',
    'except' => [
        'exception.CHttpException.404',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks  rob006 for a quick reply. Sorry I wasn't able to reply that quickly. I will try adding these settings.